# How to convert a byte in binary representation into int in java

Tags: java, string, int, byte

I have a String[] with byte values

```
String[] s = {"110","101","100","11","10","1","0"};
```

Looping through s, I want to get int values out of it.

I am currently using this

```
Byte b = new Byte(s[0]); // s[0] = 110
int result = b.intValue(); // b.intValue() is returning 110 instead of 6
```

From that, I am trying to get the results, {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

I am not sure of where to go from here. What can I do?

Thanks guys. Question answered.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the overloaded [`Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method for such a conversion. This way you can just skip the `Byte b = new Byte(s[0]);` piece of code.

```
int result = Integer.parseInt(s[0], 2); // radix 2 for binary
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using the `Byte` constructor which just takes a `String` and parses it as a *decimal* value. I think you actually want [`Byte.parseByte(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) which allows you to specify the radix:

```
for (String text : s) {
    byte value = Byte.parseByte(text, 2);
    // Use value
}
```

Note that I've used the primitive `Byte` value (as returned by `Byte.parseByte`) instead of the `Byte` wrapper (as returned by `Byte.valueOf`).

Of course, you could equally use `Integer.parseInt` or `Short.parseShort` instead of `Byte.parseByte`. Don't forget that bytes in Java are signed, so you've only got a range of [-128, 127]. In particular, you can't parse "10000000" with the code above. If you need a range of [0, 255] you might want to use `short` or `int` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly convert String bindery to decimal representation using [`Integer#parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method. No need to convert to Byte then to decimal

```
int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(s[0], 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `Byte b = Byte.valueof(s[i], 2)`. Right now it parse the string treating it as decimal value. You should use `valueOf` and pass 2 as radix.

Answer (score 1):

Skip the `Byte` step. Just parse it into an int with [`Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
int result = Integer.parseInt(s[0], 2);
```

The `2` specifies base 2, whereas the code you're using treats the input strings as decimal.